# How to slice array values by two

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array of values `[A,B,C,D,E.....]` that i need to split with this syntax:

`[ [A, B], [C, D], [E, F] ]`

and so on (it will be always a pair).

So it should be a loop that returns a string.

I've tried to do like so, and it's almost what i wanted:

```
text = '['+array[0]+','+array[1]+']';
for (index = 2; index < array.length; index++) {
    text += '['+array[index]+','+array[index+1]+']';
    console.log(text);
}
```

I get

```
[10:00,15:45][18:30,20:00]
[10:00,15:45][18:30,20:00][20:00,undefined]
```

instead i need to get only this:

```
[10:00,15:45][18:30,20:00]
```

Comment: you need to increment index by 2 each time, right?

Comment: yes, 0,1 the 2,3 then 4,5 .....

Comment: If its not exactly what you wanted would you mind to be more concrete about your question. After all we cannot read your mind...

Comment: @AdrianC. but you increment by 1 here `index++`

Comment: Check out my library implementing a method called `stride`: https://github.com/slebetman/Array.stride. With it you can simply do `array.stride(function(a,b){return '['+a+','+b+']'}).join(',')`

Comment: @slebetman nice library for this!

Comment: @aw04: This is one of those things I missed in js coming from tcl. Tcl's built-in `foreach` function can do this on its own but js has no equivalent functionality. Also, I've always wanted to use the magic my-function-can-tell-how-many-arguments-you-declared-in-your-callback feature I discovered when using mocha

Comment: @slebetman funny you mentioned that, i was actually looking at the code to see how you did it. never knew about function.length returning num of arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small method for grouping array elements. You can just check that your inner arrays have a length of 2 afterwards, if you only care about pairs.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.group) {
  Array.prototype.group = function (length) {
    var a = this.slice(), r = [];
    length = length || 1;
    
    while (a.length > 0) {
      r.push(a.splice(0, length));
    }
    
    return r;
  };
}

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'].group(2);

console.log(arr);
```

A version for if you want to discard a final group that doesn't match your expected length.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.group) {
  Array.prototype.group = function (length, req) {
    var a = this.slice(), r = [], h;
    length = length || 1;
    
    while (a.length > 0) {
      h = a.splice(0, length);
      
      if (!req || h.length === length) {
        r.push(h);
      }
    }
    
    return r;
  };
}

var arr = ['an', 'odd', 'number', 'of', 'elements'].group(2, true);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Could try making text an actual array and pushing pairs in, like so

```js
var orig=['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var text=[];
for (index = 0; index < orig.length-1; index+=2) {
    text.push([orig[index],orig[index+1]]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
}
```

Comment: If the number of values in `orig` is odd, the last value won't be pushed... `['A', 'B', 'C']` goes to `[ ['A', 'B'] ]`

Comment: He mentioned that it will always be pairs, so I was under that assumption

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
var groupArray = function(arr){
    var groupedArray = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 2){
        groupedArray.push([arr[i], arr[i + 1]]);
    }
    return groupedArray;
};
```

This obviously only works for arrays with an even number of elements. If you need the function to work with arrays with an odd number of elements, too, you need to acomodate for that.